# Paragraph begin with >>

Tags: paragraphs, overleaf

Some paragraphs of my latex document star with >> symbol, but I don't find why. Other paragraphs before star normal.
[image: Problem paragraph stars with >>]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This is only a guess, because we'd need to see your input to be sure.  It looks to me like that paragraph is being treated as a quote, and the quotation marks are set to be a style associated with a particular language (and not necessarily the language of the main text).  To be certain, more information is needed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I found the problem, at the end of a paragraph I use <<, when I delete it, the document works perfectly. However, I need to use <<, I already have Spanish babel, but it doesn't work.